# How can I rewrite with apache mod_rewrite an entire directory?

Tags: apache-httpd, mod-rewrite, rewrite

I need this URL/directory `make/lores/some/` to point/map to `login/`
I also need to rewrite `.php` extensions to `.html`

#### Example

When the client types in `example.com/make/lores/some/login.html` the server should `process example.com/login/login.php`.

I have a rule below, but  the issue is that the other files under the login directory  ( e.g., `/login/images/one.png` etc.) are not handled/rewritten so I end up with a  404 error.

```
RewriteRule     ^(.*)\.htm$     login/index.php [NC]
```

Comment: That rule will only rewrite `.htm` files to `login/index.php`. Why not make a rewrite rule for `make/lores/some/` to `login/`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps something like this:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule   ^/make/lores/some/(.+)  http://example.com/login/$1      [R,L]
```

This will handle the rewriting to the new URL. To correct the extension from `.html` to `.php` you can use a 2nd rule for that:

```
RewriteRule   ^/login/(.+)\.htm$      http://example.com/login/$1.php  [R,L]
```

#### References

- [Redirecting and Remapping with mod_rewrite](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/remapping.html)

Comment: I don't need to redirect, I need only a rewrite. Also  I need a relative URL because the server/site may be accessed under multiple domains.